# Analog scanf("%1d") for C++ (std::cin)

Tags: c++

I'm looking for some analog scanf("%1d", &sequence) for std::cin >> sequence.

For example:

```
for ( ; scanf("%1d", &sequence) == 1; ) {
    printf("%d ", sequence);
}
```

```
stdin: 5341235
```

```
stdout: 5 3 4 1 2 3 5
```

How does it work in C++ ?!

```
for ( ; std::cin >> *some_magic* sequence; ) {
    std::cout << sequence << " ";
}
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Have you actually tested that? [The documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) shows no hint that the stream width is considered for this input operation.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:yes i thought so but unfortunately it is not working http://ideone.com/Z7K5HD

Comment: After reading closer in [the `std::setw` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [the `std::num_get::get` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) (the function which does the actual parsing) it seems that the `std::setw` manipulator is only used for characters and strings, numeric parsing doesn't check for the width. So if you want to read only a single digit at a time, then you have to read a single character at a time while it's a digit.

Comment: @KerrekSB You're right, the `std::setw` manipulator can't be used for numbers.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this if you want (the `sequence` variable **must** be of type `char`)

```
for ( ; std::cin.read(&sequence,1); ) {
    sequence-='0';
    std::cout << sequence << " ";;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With respect to input parsing there are a number of features unfortunately missing from IOStreams which are present for `scanf()`. Setting a field width for numeric types is one of them (another one is matching strings in inputs). Assuming you want to stay with formatted input, one way to deal with it is to create a filtering stream buffer which injects a space character after a given number of characters.

Another approach consists of writing a custom `std::num_get<char>` facet, to `imbue()` it into the current stream, and then just set up width. Instead of injecting spaces the actual character parsing would observe if either the end of the stream is reached or the number of allowed characters is exceeded. The corresponding code to use this facet would set up a custom `std::locale` but otherwise look like one would expect:

```
int main() {
    std::istringstream in("1234567890123456789");
    std::locale loc(std::locale(), new width_num_get);
    in.imbue(loc);
    int w(0);
    for (int value(0); in >> std::setw(++w) >> value; ) {
        std::cout << "value=" << value << "\n";
    }
}
```

Here is a somewhat naive implementation of a corresponding `std::num_get<char>` facet which just collects the appropriate digits (assuming base 10) and then just calls `std::stoi()` to get the value converted. It can be done more flexible and more efficient but you get the picture:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

struct width_num_get
    : std::num_get<char> {
    auto do_get(iter_type it, iter_type end, std::ios_base& fmt,
                std::ios_base::iostate& err, long& value) const
        -> iter_type override {
        int width(fmt.width(0)), count(0);
        if (width == 0) {
            width = -1;
        }
        std::string digits;
        if (it != end && (*it == '-' || *it == '+')) {
            digits.push_back(*it++);
            ++count;
        }
        while (it != end && count != width && std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it))) {
            digits.push_back(*it);
            ++it;
            ++count;
        }
        try { value = std::stol(digits); }
        catch (...) { err |= std::ios_base::failbit; } // should probably distinguish overflow
        return it;
    }
};
```

The first described approach could use code like this for reading integers with increasing width (I'm using different width to show that it can flexibly be set):

```
int main() {
    std::istringstream in("1234567890123456789");
    int w(0);
    for (int value(0); in >> fw(++w) >> value; ) {
        std::cout << "value=" << value << "\n";
    }
}
```

Of course, the entire magic is in the little `fw()` which is a custom manipulator: it installs a filtering stream buffer if the currently used stream buffer isn't of the appropriate type and set the number for characters after which the a space should be injected. The filtering stream buffer reads individual characters and simply injects a space after the corresponding number of characters. The code could be something like this (which currently doesn't do clean-up once the stream is done - I'll add that next):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <sstream>

class fieldbuf
    : public std::streambuf {
    std::streambuf* sbuf;
    int             width;
    char            buffer[1];
    int underflow() {
        if (this->width == 0) {
            buffer[0] = ' ';
            this->width = -1;
        }
        else {
            int c = this->sbuf->snextc();
            if (c == std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
                return c;
            }
            buffer[0] = std::char_traits<char>::to_char_type(c);
            if (0 < this->width) {
                --this->width;
            }
        }
        this->setg(buffer, buffer, buffer + 1);
        return std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type(buffer[0]);
    }
public:
    fieldbuf(std::streambuf* sbuf): sbuf(sbuf), width(-1)  {}
    void setwidth(int width) { this->width = width; }
};

struct fw {
    int width;
    fw(int width): width(width) {}
};
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, fw const& width) {
    fieldbuf* fbuf(dynamic_cast<fieldbuf*>(in.rdbuf()));
    if (!fbuf) {
        fbuf = new fieldbuf(in.rdbuf());
        in.rdbuf(fbuf);
        static int index = std::ios_base::xalloc();
        in.pword(index) = fbuf;
        in.register_callback([](std::ios_base::event ev, std::ios_base& stream, int index){
                if (ev == std::ios_base::copyfmt_event) {
                    stream.pword(index) = 0;
                }
                else if (ev == std::ios_base::erase_event) {
                    delete static_cast<fieldbuf*>(stream.pword(index));
                    stream.pword(index) = 0;
                }
            }, index);
    }
    fbuf->setwidth(width.width);
    return in;
}
```